# Cannot find module '@chainlink/contracts/truffle/v0.4/LinkToken'

Tags: truffle-migration, truffle-deployment, chainlink

I was following [these steps](https://docs.chain.link/docs/create-a-chainlinked-project/) in order to use Chainlink on Kovan testnet. when I've finished the configuration (`truffle-config.js`, `npm install` to get all the dependencies, etc.) and I've compiled the contracts and all is working. But when I was doing:

> truffle migrate --network kovan

I got an error about it couldn't find the module `@chainlink/contracts/truffle/v0.4/LinkToken`. I've tried to find a solution on Internet but I didn't find anything.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are you need to change require lines as below.

```
const { LinkToken } = require('../node_modules/@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.4/LinkToken.sol')
const { Oracle } = require('../node_modules/@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/Oracle.sol')
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot, that helped a lot. But...

[image]

Now I'm getting this error (Chainlink is driving me crazy...). ¿Unexpected identifier? I also tried to change that line to v6.0, but there's no `LinkToken.sol` file in v6.0 folder (that file only exists in v4.0). So that didn't work either.

I don't know... Maybe something about the compiler? But I can't change the compiler either. I need to use compiler 0.6.6.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use @chainlink/contracts with truffle you should use the truffle unbox or change the @chainlink/contracts version to 0.1.9.

Ethers and Truffle contract artifacts are no longer published in further versions.

Comment: Finally I changed the project to Hardhat. Much better. Thanks!